# Error while creating URI with com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource adding String value to path

Tags: rest, webresource

Using com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client,ClientResponse and WebResource.

```
    Client client = this.client;
    WebResource webResource = null;
    ClientResponse response = null;
    String url = "";
```

url = "https://test.com/rest/V1/cart/" + quoteId + "/items";

```
    webResource = client.resource(url);

    String jsonString = "{\"cartItem\":{\"quote_id\":" + quoteId + ",\"id\": " + id+ ",\"qty\":" + qty + "}}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
        JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(jsonString);
        JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(parser);

        response = webResource.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.token).type("application/json")
                .post(ClientResponse.class, actualObj);
```

I have error

> Illegal character in path at index 52: https://test.com/rest/V1/cart/"IerwexsKLchKYmZ1ryKZkor9RdfJ2Dp3"/items

I am passing quoteId as parameter `String quoteId="IerwexsKLchKYmZ1ryKZkor9RdfJ2Dp3";`

How to remove quotes for quoteId from URL?
Thank you.